# Magento 2 : How can i add custom customer address field in e-mail template?

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, customer-address, magento-2.0.7, billing-address

I have added one custom Field for customer address, and i want to display in checkout page, customer my account section and in All sales email template (In Billing and Shipping Address). Please help me, Thanks in advance.

I am using Magento 2.0.7

Comment: did you found any solution? I need same like that look here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216191/shipping-address-custom-attribute-value-not-display-in-address-box-in-magento2

Comment: Natively I don't think this is possible, as not all e-mail will have customer or customer in their contexts, so only store info is available through variables